# elasticsearch does index size includes _source?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

My document source contains 10 fields but I index only 2 of them. I don't index the remaining fields but the raw size ratio of 2 indexed fields vs remaining 8 is 20% : 80%

**Question** - from the documentation, I understand elasticsearch loads the index data into memory. Does this include "_source" field or just the indexed field data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index size = size(_source) + size(indexed fields) + size (_all) + size(store if enabled)